# Create a cart with Magento api and iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento

In my app I will to add an object to a remote Magento cart. So my app has a `viewController` in which I select the product I want, when I tap on the product it presents me another `viewController` in which I can read the details of the products. Now I put a button in this `viewController` to add the product to a cart.
I tried the `Magento` e-commerce on my browser and I saw that when I click on the button "Add to Cart" it sends an http request to the server with this address:

```
http://54.204.6.246/magento8/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzU0LjIwNC42LjI0Ni9tYWdlbnRvOC9zcGVjaWFsLXNhbGVzLmh0bWw,/product/1/form_key/Zqmpp3fnpuTtxI4b/
```

In this way I put the product in the remote cart of `Magento`. Now I want to do the same things with my `iOS` app, so I wrote the following code:

```
#import "CreateCarriage.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"

@implementation CreateCarriage{
    NSMutableData *datas;
}

- (void)createCarriageWithProductID:(NSString *)productID {

    NSString *addProductLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://54.204.6.246/magento8/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzU0LjIwNC42LjI0Ni9tYWdlbnRvOC9zcGVjaWFsLXNhbGVzLmh0bWw,/product/%@/form_key/Zqmpp3fnpuTtxI4b/", productID];
    [self sendRequestToURL:addProductLink withMethod:@"GET"];
}

- (id)sendRequestToURL:(NSString *)url withMethod:(NSString *)method {
    NSURL *finalUrl;
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
        finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Metodo non previsto");
    }
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    NSString *authStr = @"user:password";
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedString]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
//    [request setValue:@"x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    NSLog(@"%@", request);

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        [connection start];
    }
    return connection;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    datas = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    [datas appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Oggetto aggiunto al carrello");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

@end
```

But when I run the app it shows me this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
      <title>401 Authorization Required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Authorization Required</h1>
     <p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.</p>
     <hr>
     <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 54.204.6.246 Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's wrong in my code? The user and the password I set in the code are correct indeed if I try them on a normal browser they works.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not support HTTP Basic Authentication. The URL which you are using above will add product with id=1 to the "current" user's shopping cart, where the "current" user is identified by session cookies. Your iOS native app will not maintain cookies, so the above snippet will not work even if you solve the HTTP authentication problem.

The HTTP authentication error is most likely due to an incorrect server configuration/username-password. Check your Apache configuration (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html). The reason it is working in your browser is because it accepts cookies and thus, Magento is able to maintain your session.

If you want to authenticate your Magento customers, you will have to use Magento's APIs. You can use either the SOAP API (www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) or the REST API (www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html).

Both of them however have their own set of problems. You might want to have a look at MobStac's iOS SDK for Magento. In addition to customers' cart syncing between desktop and mobile, it also has support for fetching catalog information and payments. Visit http://developer.mobstac.com/ for more details. Disclaimer: I work for MobStac.